# Compile GLFW Static Libraries in Windows for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, compilation, static-libraries, glfw

Sorry in advance if this is a really simple question or if this has already been answered somewhere. I searched for myself but couldn't find the exact answer to my problem.

I'm following the GLFW documentation to compile the GLFW libraries using CMake. I managed to make the build files, but then the documentation says "Go ahead and compile the actual GLFW library with these files, as you would with any other project."

Unfortunately, IDK how I would compile the library as I would with any other project since I don't see any files I recognize (like .h header files or .cpp files). Instead, I see a bunch of .vcxproj files and a .sln file. I'm unfamiliar with any of these files lol.

So my question is, how would I proceed from here to build a static .lib? Thank you in advance!
Build Output:
[image]

Build Directory:
[image]

Compiling GLFW Documentation
[image]

Comment: You build the solution that is in the build directory.

Comment: ***Instead I see a bunch of .vcxproj files and a .sln file. I'm unfamiliar with any of these files lol.*** You must be new to Visual Studio. These are the project files that Visual Studio uses for every project.  You could just open the .sln file in Visual Studio and build from there.

Comment: An alternate method could be `cmake --build .` in the build folder

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you for the explanation! This resulted in a .lib file being created inside a Debug folder. I assume this is the correct library?

Comment: That is the Debug version of the library. `cmake --build . --config Release` should build the Release / optimized version.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so I can give you best answer?

Answer (score 0):

The build folder will contain a solution file (has a `.sln` extension) and all the project files (among other generated files) needed to build GLFW. To build you can open the `.sln` file in `Visual Studio` and build the Debug and Release configurations directly from the IDE or you can change directory to the build folder and execute this command:

```
cmake --build .
```

to build the debug versions of the library or

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

to build the release version.